# Method after onResume()

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to get mess with a webview to display Latex with javascript.

I want to do this as the activity loads. I get an error.

However, if I use a button to command it to update the webview, it works.

Are there any methods past `onResume` which would be called the moment the activity is completely loaded? The error I am getting is:

`Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT`

and

`onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached.`

I think this is because the webview is not fully loaded when I am calling it in an `onResume` method.

Comment: please provide some code or better way to reproduce this error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I ended up finding it out.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding out the answer. If you are trying to parse javascript in the oncreate method, you need to use a webviewclient.

```html
        w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                String s = latexStuff.getRandomExample(getApplication());
                view.evaluateJavascript("javascript:document.getElementById('mmlout').innerHTML='';", null);
                view.evaluateJavascript("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='\\\\["
                        + s + "\\\\]';", null);
                view.evaluateJavascript("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);", null);
            }
        });
```

In this example, w is my webview and I am adding the latex code here.